# Linq set a property in a list?

Tags: linq

Model

```
class MeterReadingTypes 
{
    int id { get; set;}
    bool isSelected { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; } 
    .....
}
```

Linq

```
entity.MeterReadingTypes;
```

There are records that has true or false value, and I want to set only one value to true, others false.

Orginal List

```
id | isSelected | Name |
------------------------
 1 |      false |    A |
 2 |      false |    B |
 3 |       true |    C |
 3 |       true |    D |
 5 |      false |    E |
 6 |      false |    F |
 7 |       true |    G |
```

I want to set this list to following:

```
id | isSelected | .. |
-----------------
 1 |      false |    A |
 2 |      false |    B |
 3 |       true |    C |
 4 |      false |    D |
 5 |      false |    E |
 6 |      false |    F |
 7 |      false |    G |
```

Can I do this , I want only one property to set to `true`?

**EDIT**

My solution

```
List<OsosPlus2.Core.DataAccess.MeterReadingTypes> types = new List<Core.DataAccess.MeterReadingTypes>();

foreach (var unselectedTypes in entity.MeterReadingTypes)
{
    if(unselectedTypes.Name == "C") unselectedTypes.IsSelected = true;
    unselectedTypes.IsSelected = false;
    types.Add(unselectedTypes);
}

return PartialView(types);
```

Is there any elegant solution?

Comment: Both `Select` and `Where` are about *querying*, not *setting* properties. (And indeed that's what LINQ is aimed at.) It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve at the moment.

Comment: Sorry I mean .select(x => new { isSelected = true})

Comment: How would you identify which item to set to `true`?

Comment: @GertArnold, not important, it may be first, last or specified place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Q' in LINQ stands for query. Queries don't update anything, so LINQ is not the correct way to update your objects. The easiest and most concise solution would be this:

```
foreach(var type in entity.MeterReadingTypes)
    type.IsSelected = type.MeterType == typeId;
```

If you insist on using some LINQ, you could go with this:

```
foreach(var unselectedType in entity.MeterReadingTypes
                                    .Where(x => x.MeterType != typeId))
{
    unselectedType.IsSelected = false;
}

foreach(var selectedType in entity.MeterReadingTypes
                                  .Where(x => x.MeterType == typeId))
{
    selectedType.IsSelected = true;
}
```

As you can see, it makes the code a lot longer.

Another approach would be this:

```
entity.MeterReadingTypes.Select(x => { x.IsSelected = types.MeterType == typeId;
                                       return x; });
```

Again, no advantage to the simple `foreach` version.

Answer (score 0):

You solution will set all items unselected because `unselectedTypes.IsSelected = false;` comes last. You can do this:

```
foreach (var unselectedType in entity.MeterReadingTypes)
{
    unselectedType.IsSelected = (unselectedType.Name == "C");
}
```